# Lost color on hover transition in Safari 13, is this a bug?

Tags: html, css, macos, colors, safari

I found that under certain CSS conditions the color of a link will turn transparent on hover (and then remain transparent) in Safari 13 (which is the current version of Safari on older versions of macOS). I guess this is a bug, because it doesn't happen in Safari 14.

This is the combination of CSS rules that triggers this behaviour:

```
:root {
    --my-color: color(display-p3 1 0 0);
}
* {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
a {
    transition: all .15s linear;
    color: var(--my-color);
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The color will change from `color(display-p3 1 0 0)` to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` according to the web inspector in Safari 13.

I've created a CodePen and I guess my question is; can someone confirm this behaviour in Safari 13?
https://codepen.io/aetles/pen/WNRWeya

Comment: TIL about the color function and `display-p3` in CSS https://css-tricks.com/the-expanding-gamut-of-color-on-the-web/#the-css-color-function-and-display-p3-colorspace

Comment: As to your question: If the behavior has changed from an older version of Safari to a newer version I would treat the old behavior as the exception

Comment: @Dominik Yeah, I aslo learned about the those things when I was troubleshooting this, actually landed on the very same CSS-Tricks article.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not a bug. Safari has certain limitations with HTML.

Rather than having `color: var(--my-color)` have `color: #COLOR`.

Safari is not as good with handling HTML, CSS and Javascript files as google, this may help.

If not, sorry, i have no answer.

Comment: No, Safari 13 supports CSS variables just fine in general, even the color() functions with colorspace and all. It's just this exact combination of rules with this CSS transition on hover that is causing this error (which I still think is a bug).

Comment: Being "not good at handling HTML, CSS and JS" is the same as "bug" in my book.